# How can I enable --verbose-versions for apt-get and apt by default?

Tags: apt

`apt-get` and `apt` have a very useful option `--verbose-versions` (or `-V` for short) that shows you version numbers in its output. For instance:

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade --verbose-versions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
   firefox (53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.17.04.2 => 54.0+build3-0ubuntu0.17.04.1)
   firefox-locale-ar (53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.17.04.2 => 54.0+build3-0ubuntu0.17.04.1)
   firefox-locale-en (53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.17.04.2 => 54.0+build3-0ubuntu0.17.04.1)
   firefox-locale-es (53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.17.04.2 => 54.0+build3-0ubuntu0.17.04.1)
   firefox-locale-zh-hans (53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.17.04.2 => 54.0+build3-0ubuntu0.17.04.1)
```

How can I enable this option by default?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put ...

```
APT::Get::Show-Versions "true";
```

in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. That file probably does not exist yet.

[Man page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt-get.8.en.html) shows that as the "configuration option".

> **/etc/apt/apt.conf**
>
> APT configuration file. Configuration Item: Dir::Etc::Main.

You probably can also use ...

> **/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/**
>
> APT configuration file fragments. Configuration Item: Dir::Etc::Parts.

and create a "file fragment" for this option.

Comment: hmm. Can you try without the ";" at the end? I thought it was mandatory but now in doubt. edit: nah cant be it. Seems to be ok like I posted when looking at this https://wiki.debian.org/AptConf